# How to load external data in the replicator activity in a sharepoint sequential workflow?

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sequential-workflow

I'm trying to make a really simple sequential workflow on sharepoint. The target of this worflow is doing a repetitive task creation over an item added. My problem is that the number of task tobe generated are stored in a sharepoint list so, before the replicator activity runs I have to check this list and get the number of task to be created sequently. When I do this operation the workflow only creates one task and the workflow status is "finished". However, If I set the number of task with a constant the workflow works fine.

The question is why if I get the number of task from an external source the workflow doesn't work, but if I put a constant number of tasks the workflow works well??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When the workflow is first activated, query this list and get the tasks to be created (along with any other info you might need) and place it into a global IList.

In your workflow design, simply bind the global IList to the InitialChildData property of the Replicator activity.